# When I start my Minecraft Animation, the FPS is drop down about 2ˇˇ3

Tags: animation, frame-rate

When I'm editing my animation there is no issue with FPS, but when I press "space" to start the animation, the fps drop down very low, to about 2-3.

My specification: gtx 1650 and ryzen 5 1600, so I think this is not problem.

Comment: You can see a page  on GPU Strengths on the internet. [https://www.videocardbenchmark.net]  Please show your work as a few Blender Screen captures.  The interface and a render.  If you have enough tasks you can slow down any computer.  Fluid and Smoke and Particle simulations are baked so as to reduce further computations.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know why your scene in particular might be slow without more information but since playback in particular is slow then you should consider things in your scene that are only calculated *during playback*.

For example:

- Simulated objects (e.g. rigid body or soft body dynamics)
- Particle systems
- Fluids

You could try disabling parts of your scene to narrow down what might be slowing things down: maybe a specific object or set of objects?

If you find that it's a simulation of some sort, consider baking it to a cache.

If it's a complex modifier you may be able to export that object to an Alembic cache and use that to reduce the cost.

Finally, if your scene is simply way too complex you may want to split it into smaller pieces, do your animation in a simpler scene, then create a master scene that references all the pieces to create your final render, where you expect each frame to take a long time anyway.